# calender day. myCalendar.addDisabledDates

Tags: javascript, calendar

I want to use Calender.addDisabledDates to disable dates before specific date. For example, I want to disable the dates before 1 February 2014. I used the code below.

```
myCalendar.addDisabledDates(null,2014 + "-" +2 + "-" +1);
```

However, when I try to select the date, 01 February 2014 is disabled. I don't want this date to be disabled. Enabled dates should start from that day.  How can I solve this problem?
Regards,

Comment: I am guessing this is javascript. Can you post your code as well?

Comment: I solved this problem by using this. getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH); I took the last day of the month and disabled it to that day. However, the previous code must have been worked.I dont understand why it doesn't work.